# Assistance with taking matrix to power of constant

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, numpy

below i have provided all my code for this program I am trying to develop. What this takes as in input is an N x 3 file; i will provide the sample of what im using below (its just a 5x3 sample). Each sample represents a co-ordinate of a pixel in an image, which has been scaled to some XYZ co-ordinate using multidimensional scaling.The purpose of this program is to go from XYZ co-ordinates, to LaB color... which can then be translated into sRGB. The code below (the second portion) shows the transformation from XYZ to LaB, and the upper portion (labelled Fast XYZ - RGB) is a shortcut i found to go from XYZ to RGB cutting out the LaB step. The problem resides in the Fast XYZ - RGB step.

What i am trying to do is make the sRGBmat = (1 + val) * RGBLin ^ (1/2.4) - val

The problem that i keep running into is that of RGBLin can sometimes be a negative number... which means i have to use Cmath or something else. I tried using Cmath, but it gave me the incorrect values-
In MatLab, it gives me a proper number, (well a real + imaginary part), which i can still use.

The file xyztest.txt contains a 5x3 matrix with the following values:

```
.2345   .9817   .7612
.5465   .7897   .3514
.7796   .6765   .5645
.1221   .6376   .8790
.5432   .5853   .4652
```

The output should (with a few more computations) result in an N x 3 matrix, where each row is representative of the RGB values at pixel 1-n of row 1 (for the first n values), then row 2 for the next n+1 values-

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
d=open('xyztest.txt', 'r')
import cmath

a=[]
count = 0
b = []
AoverAn = []
XoX = []
YoY = []
ZoZ = []
aova=[]
c = 0
while 1:
    line = d.readline()
    a.append(line.split())
    count = count + 1
    if not line:
        break
#print a #contains all of the line elements in a list
t=[]
XYZM = []

illuminant = [94.9423, 100.0000, 108.7201]
##or is it [ .9424, 1.000, .8249] which is in matlab-

#print count
for i in range(count-1):
    b = a[i:(i+1)]
    #print "this is", b
    c = b[0]
    x = c[0]
    y = c[1]
    z = c[2]
    XoverXn = round(float(x) /illuminant [0], 10)
    YoverYn = round(float(y) / illuminant [1], 10)
    ZoverZn = round(float(z) / illuminant [2], 10)
    XoX.append(XoverXn)
    YoY.append(YoverYn)
    ZoZ.append(ZoverZn)
    x.replace('\'', '')
    mmaker = (float("".join(x)), float("".join(y)), float("".join(z)))
    XYZM.append(mmaker)

L = []
a = []
b = []
fXoX = []
fYoY = []
fZoZ = []
Lab = []

##print "YOUR XYZ MAT", XYZM
##Get an XYZ matrix so i can use fast XYZ to RGB
```

Fast XYZ > RGB

```
##A is the thing we want to multiply
A= np.matrix('3.2410, -1.5374, -0.4986 ;-.9692, 1.8760, 0.0416 ; .0556, -.2040, 1.0570')

##we get [R,G,B]' = A * [X,Y,Z]'
##Must be in the range 0-1 
RGBLin=[]
##XYZM = float(XYZM)
print "XYZ"
print XYZM
xyzt = np.transpose(np.matrix(XYZM))
RGBLin = np.transpose(A * xyzt)


val = 0.555
temp = (RGBLin <= 0.00304)
#print temp


print "RGB"
##print RGBLin
## Do power multiplcation because numpy doesnt want to work for non square mat
for i in range(len(RGBLin)):
    for j in range(1):  
        rgbline = RGBLin[i].tolist()
        for item in rgbline:
            for i in range(3):
                print item[i]
                item[i] = 1.055 + item[i+1]**(1/2.4)
                print item[i]
            print item
        #print rgbline
        #te[i][j] = pow(RGBLin[i][j] , (1./2.4))
#print te
```

-> The problem resides in this step, i am trying to take the matrix to the power of (1/2.4), but some values of the matrix are negative- How do i get python to give me a value??!

```
#te = pow(RGBLin, (1./2.4))
```

XYZ -> LAB

```
for i in range(len(XoX)):
    #print YoY[i]

    xyz = []

    test = float(pow(YoY[i],(1./3)))
    #print test
    if (YoY[i] > 0.008856):
        L.append((116 * (YoY[i] **(1./3))) - 16)               
        #L1 = (116 * (YoY[i] **(1./3))) - 16
    else:
        L.append(903.3* YoY[i])
        #L1 = 903.3* YoY[i]
    ##    
    if (XoX[i] > 0.008856):
        fXoX.append(pow(XoX[i], (1./3)))
        #A1 = pow(XoX[i], (1./3))
    else:
        fXoX.append((7.787 * XoX[i])+(16/116))
        #A1 = (7.787 * XoX[i])+(16/116)
    ##   
    if (YoY[i] > 0.008856):
        fYoY.append(pow(YoY[i], (1./3)))
        #B1 = pow(YoY[i], (1./3))
    else:
        fYoY.append((7.787 * YoY[i])+(16/116))
        #B1 = (7.787 * YoY[i])+(16/116)
    ##
    if (ZoZ[i] > 0.008856):
        fZoZ.append(pow(ZoZ[i], (1./3)))
        #Z1 = pow(ZoZ[i], (1./3))
    else:
        fZoZ.append((7.787 * ZoZ[i])+(16/116))
        #Z1 = (7.787 * ZoZ[i])+(16/116)
    ##

    a.append(500*(fXoX[i]-fYoY[i]))
    b.append(500*(fYoY[i]-fZoZ[i]))
    xyz.append((L[i], a[i], b[i]))
    ##print xyz
######### NOW we must go from Lab to RGB, where XYZ is the LaB co-ordinates######
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell numpy that your numbers are complex.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: r = np.array([-5, 2, 8, -1])

In [3]: r ** (1/2.4)
/usr/local/share/python3/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
   #!/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.2.2/bin/python3.2
Out[3]: array([        nan,  1.33483985,  2.37841423,         nan])

In [4]: c = r.astype(complex)

In [5]: c ** (1/2.4)
Out[5]: 
array([ 0.50609696+1.88877958j,  1.33483985+0.j        ,
        2.37841423+0.j        ,  0.25881905+0.96592583j])
```

There's some discussion of this [on scipy.org](http://www.scipy.org/NegativeSquareRoot).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; the next problem i am running into is the one where its asking me to input a square array... My real data set is an 1173 x 3 matrix... How do i bypass this issue? Or would the best way to do it be to break it into a 3x3 matrix through a for loop-

Comment: @J3210 Where's it asking you for a square array? (It's hard to wade through the long chunk of code you posted.) It should only ask for a square array if you're doing something like an inverse or whatever that actually needs to be square.